# How can i do with this problem (apisix-dashboard run)

Tags: apache-apisix

i install and run etcd ,apisix ; but run the apisix-dashboard had error like this。

{"level":"warn","ts":"2023-04-07T11:24:14.718Z","logger":"etcd-client","caller":"v3@v3.5.5/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"etcd-endpoints://0xc0005f6700/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest balancer error: last connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused""}
Error: etcd get failed: context deadline exceeded
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNTd7.png)

the apisix-dashboard config.yaml like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw6uD.png)

can any one help me ?

the etcd version:3.4.3
the apisix version :3.2.0-centos
the apisix-dashboard versin:3.0.0-centos

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that apisix dashboard cannot connect to etcd. This error has several reasons. The first thing to check is that etcd is started properly. Although telnet shows that port 2379 is listening, it is not the reason that etcd is started correctly. If you have started apisix as docker, the situation will be different.

Comment: In my case I have been running both etcd and apisix in docker environment, that time also I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use the below configuration for apisix dashboard.

```yaml
conf:
  listen:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 9000
  etcd:
    endpoints:
      - etcd:2379
  log:
    error_log:
      level: warn
      file_path: /dev/stderr
    access_log:
      file_path: /dev/stdout
authentication:
  secert: secert
  expire_time: 3600
  users:
    - username: admin
      password: apisixadmin
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**